# Unexpected break during an if statement C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The program is to convert yen, euro or pounds (depending on user input) to a dollar.
I am asking 2 user inputs - double amount (money to convert) and char currency (to determine what currency to convert to dollar).
Sample Input: 1y 
Sample Output: 1 yen(s) = 0.0094 dollar(s).
The problem is in the if-else block when I am trying to convert euros to dollars, it breaks the while loop. Here, is my code:

```cpp
double amount; // the amount of money to be converted
char currency; // to determine the currency in which the money is being entered in.
    while (cin >> amount >> currency) {
        if (currency == 'y' || currency == 'Y') {
            cout << amount << " yen(s) = " << (amount * 0.0094) << " dollar(s).\n";
        }
        else if (currency == 'e' || currency == 'E') {
            cout << amount << " euro(s) = " << (amount * 1.13) << " dollar(s).\n";
        }
        else if (currency == 'p' || currency == 'P') {
            cout << amount << " pound(s) = " << (amount * 1.25) << " dollar(s).\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Sorry I did not recognize the currency! Please enter 'y','e' or 'p'.\n";
        }
        cout << "Please enter the amount of money and corresponding currency to covert to  dollars: ";
    }
```

As evidence here are the images of my input and output:

### Conversion of euros to dollar error one

[image: Conversion of euros to dollar error one]

### Conversion of euros to dollar error two

[image: Conversion of euros to dollar error two]

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question. What is `amount` and `currency` ?

Comment: Probably when you enter `1e` or `2E`, the program treats it as a single value (scientific notation) and exits your `while` loop.

Comment: 1Y and 1P can be interpreted as 1 decimal number, and 1 character, but 1E can be interpreted as a single hexadecimal number, with no character, breaking the loop's condition.

Comment: @vahancho That is a plausible explanation. But I am entering 'e' as a character and not as a keyword?

Comment: how about separate the number and currency by space?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I have not posted the entire code. I have only posted a section of code where I believe where the error lies? I cant minimize this code further? Like I mentioned in the question: amount is the money that is to be converted to dollars and currency is a char variable that determines which currency is the money being entered in. Please read the question! Thanks!

Comment: @K.R.Park Yea it works when I use a space. It does not work when I do not use a space. But others work with and without a space.

Comment: @Shayna How is 1E interpreted as a hexadecimal number when 1 is stored in a double variable and 'E' is stored in a char variable?

Comment: [Scientific notation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/scientific/) 1E is interpreted as a number, not as a number and a char. The complete input is read into `amount` and removed from `cin`. There is no character left for `currency`.

Comment: @ProgrammingRage Because the first call to the >> operator (cin >> amount) is not aware of the second call, it simply returns a reference to cin which the second call uses as the first argument. It isn't aware of currency's existence, and so when it reads "1E", it stores it into amount, because 1E translates into decimal 30, which fits into a double. Then when the second call occurs, there are no characters left to process.

Comment: But in this statement `while (cin >> amount >> currency)` 1 would go in double amount variable and E would go in char currency variable. So, are you saying that 1E is interpreted as 1 number even tho they are stored in 2 different variables with different type?

Comment: @Shayna Oh I see! Thank you! So, how do I fix this issue?

Comment: @ProgrammingRage Actually, as I just suggested, you can just add a space between the number and currency to settle the issue. That's the C++ way to separate the input.

Comment: You could read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt. I'm not sure if there is a solution. A different approach is to read the input character by character.

Comment: @ProgrammingRage I did a bit of testing on my end, and I think it's probably interpreting it as scientific notation, not hexadecimal. The same principle still applies though. If you want to maintain the same syntax, then you could try reading it as a string into a buffer, then indexing into the last character of the string to get the currency character, then writing a nullbyte to that character once you've stored it elsewhere, and convert the remaining string into a double.

Comment: @Shayna "_and so when it reads "1E", it stores it into amount, because 1E translates into decimal 30, which fits into a double._" No it doesn't. Did you try verifying your claim, before you made it? `std::cin`, can read numbers in scientific notation (e.g. 1E+1), so when it sees `1E`, it expects the number in this form, but since there is no exponent - `std::cin` fails. That is why the loop stops: due to the failed input operation.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yeah, I realized that after the fact. That's what comments are for I suppose, haha

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Oh! So it reads entire 1E as 1 number and it expects +1 as a format. Aah! This is interesting because this is a loop within a loop technically. Even then, if the correct format is not provided, should it not assume a default format to avoid such discrepancy and possible unexpected breaks in the program?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I tried this input: "1e+1e" and it worked the way I expected it to work!

Comment: @ThomasSablik I went through that link, but unfortunately I did not understand anything because I have just started to learn programming.

Comment: I wasnt asking to minimize the code further, but to add the missing details. You only mention it in the text what are the types, but in the code the declaration is missing. It is always easier if your code can  be copied by others to reproduce the same problem you are facing

Comment: @idclev463035818 I have edited the question and added the variables as you asked. Is it ok now?

Comment: yes much better. The reason I am picky about it is that with different types or with just a few lines of code added the behavior can be completely different. Now your code is more or less complete enough to see the same problem as you do (apart from includes and some using statements, which would be nice to have, but well yeah ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yea, I understand. I will keep that in mind, the next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide an actual answer, since I can't do so in the comments; here's an alternate way of getting the relevant user input, maintaining the same syntax. This assumes that the last character of the input string is the currency character. You can perform a check to see if the last character is a valid currency character, but here's a simplified version.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string input_string;
    std::getline(std::cin, input_string);

    if(input_string.size() >= 2) {
        char currency = input_string[input_string.size() - 1];
        input_string[input_string.size() - 1] = '\0';
        double amount = std::stof(input_string);

        std::cout << amount << std::endl;
        std::cout << currency << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have >= 2 in your condition? Should it not be "== 2"? Because I would only accept 2 characters and not more or less.

Comment: @ProgrammingRage Because you could have an amount such as 56.573, which is still a valid double. But if you want to restrict it to numbers 0-9 then you can replace it with a ==.

Comment: @ProgrammingRage If your input is always one digit and one character make `amount` an integer and the whole problem is solved. There is no scientific notation for integer numbers.

Comment: Oh yea! True. Thanks a million! Also, since I am a beginner thanks for not being hard on me!

Comment: @ThomasSablik Oh ok! Thank you all for your great help!

Comment: @ProgrammingRage No problem :) StackOverflow can be pretty cruel at times, I've experienced it firsthand. The last thing I want to be is the cause of it.

Comment: That `if` statement should also check that `input_string.size() > 0`; that way you don't need those expensive calls to `input_string.at(whatever)`; you can simply write `input_string[whatever]`.

Comment: And while I'm giving advice: `std::stof(input_string)` is a better approach than `atof(input_string.c_str())`.

Comment: And, finally, break that habit of using `std::endl`; `'\n'` ends a line, without the extra stuff that `std::endl` does.

Comment: @PeteBecker I updated my answer. I completely forgot about `std::stof`'s existence, you're right, it's much more straightforward. Also, the benefits of `.at()` don't really apply here, since bounds checking is made redundant by `input_string.size() >= 2` knowing that I'll only ever be indexing into the last element, so you're right on that too, using `[]` in place of `.at()` is free performance in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`amount` is a floating-point variable. And `1e` is the start of a floating-point number; the `e` is the exponent prefix, as in `1e5=10000.0`.

So `cin` sees `1e` as an ill-formed floating-point number, and aborts the operation, returning `false` (and returning `0.0` in the `amount` variable, while leaving `currency` unchanged). If you declare `amount` as `int`, it works as you expect.

Or you could use Shayna's solution.

Comment: Is there not a default format in case the user enters just '1e' to avoid unexpected breaks and such discrepancies? I believe this is important because, it would yield some result rather than none and while debugging i could have figured it out on my own as to why this output rather than having nothing?

Comment: @ProgrammingRage: I don't understand your question. (BTW, I never use `cin` myself except in throwaway code. It is much too rigid.)

Comment: So cin sees 1e as a number and expects a format such as '1e+1' as a scientific notation. So, if the user just types '1e' the algorithm that they must have used will break because it does not confine to the format. Now, if there was a default number in case the user does not enter the entire format, it would not break and would give some output. That output would be incorrect, but atleast it would tell me the reason why the output is incorrect. For example if I just type 2e, it should automatically change to 2e+1 or some other default format. Right?

Comment: @ProgrammingRage: No, that's not how programming languages work. It would be wrong to report a made-up number like that.

Comment: @ProgrammingRage -- `double amount; std::cin >> amount;` In that code, the `>>` operator is chosen that reads a `double` value. "1e" is not a valid double value. After that happens, `if (std::cin)` will see `std::cin` as `false`. That's how you recover: check whether the input succeeded.

Comment: @PeteBecker The input did not succeed at all. It broke.

Comment: @ProgrammingRage -- yes, that's the point: once the input has failed the program has to deal with it. That means checking whether it succeeded, and if it didn't, deciding what to do.

Comment: @PeteBecker Hey, I know it is out of the blue, but I need a mentor since, I am studying C++ all by myself and I would like to have as in-depth knowledge as you do! I am currently going through the Bjarne Stroustroup Book but any guidance would be best! Thanks!